# How can I create layout like this?

Tags: android, layout, alarm

I want create an App so that the user can add some alarm like pic below. I mean that must be able to add another parameter to its self (new alarm ) .
thanks for your great answer ;)

[image: Alarm clock]

Comment: You can make this with ActionBar and ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my problem is about add new thing to layout

You have to use a `ListView` and everytime you want to add another row to your `ListView` you just update the dataset of your `ListView` adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use LsitView find some help on
[Click Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

It is helpfull

Comment: If you include the relevant parts of the page you link to here, then this will become a much better answer.